# Uncaught runtime errors (auth.signInWithPopup is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase

im trying to remake an outdated React + firebase web chatapp tutorial by fireship. so far i managed to repair some of the codes, but im stuck with this error when running the code in my browser.

[This is the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8QCh.png):

This is The App.js code

```
import React, {  useState, useRef }  from 'react' ;


import './App.css';

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth'; 
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';


firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC8HBDrU54iVmhpCAuhmI-YJKtNN_qO-IM",
  authDomain: "sociabay-e605b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sociabay-e605b",
  storageBucket: "sociabay-e605b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "721751255431",
  appId: "1:721751255431:web:191fe86d6430f9ae60cb22",
  measurementId: "G-CF8CL4LX24"
});
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebase);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const firestore = firebase.firestore();



function App() {

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>⚛️</h1>
        <SignOut />
      </header>

      <section>
        {user ? <ChatRoom/> : <SignIn/>}
      </section>
      
    </div>
  );
}

function SignIn(){
  
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
      <p>Do not violate the community guidelines or you will be banned for life!</p>
    </>
  )

}
 function SignOut() {
    return auth.currentUser && (

      <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
      )
 }

 function ChatRoom() {
  const dummy = useRef()
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query,{idfield:'id '}); 

  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState ('');


  const sendMessage = async(e)=> {

      e.preventDefault(); 

      const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;

      await messagesRef.add({
        text: formValue,
        createdAt : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        uid,
        photoURL
      });

    setFormValue('');
    dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    
   }

  return (
  <>
      <main>
        {messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}

        <div>ref={dummy} </div>
      
      </main>

      <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>

        <input value ={formValue} onChange={(e)=> setFormValue(e.target.value)} />
        
        <button type ="submit">️</button>

      </form>
  </>
)
}
  

  
function ChatMessage (props) {
  const { text, uid, photoURL } = props.message;

  const messageClass = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';
  
  return (<>
  <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={photoURL || 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png' } alt="TEXT"/>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  </>)
}

export default App;
```

the main display has no problem but when i pressed sign in it shows an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NidWL.png)
It Supposed to show google login popup when is press sign in but it doesn't work. it just shows error

I hope i give enough information for you guys to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Update, Just Fixed it somehow, i tried changing the sign in statement with other style and reverting back to original and it fixed somehow. weird